# pagination in php with mysql

Tags: php, pagination

I wonder how to easily make pagination in PHP with MySQL.. May I ask you a favor of you?
This my code have not error... take this code with your project implement..

```
 <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM json_data";  
    $rs_result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result1);

    //print_r($rs_result1); die();
    $limit = 10;  
    $total_records = $row;  
    //$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit)-220; 
     // calculate total pages
     $total_pages = ceil($row / $limit);

     $prev = $page-1;
     $next = $page+1; 
     $pagination_buttons =5;
     $last_page = $total_pages;
     $half = floor($pagination_buttons/2);

     //echo '<ul class="pagination">';
              if($page >= 5){
              echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page=1">First</a></li>';
              } 

             if($page < $pagination_buttons AND ($last_page == $pagination_buttons OR $last_page > $pagination_buttons)){

               for($i=1; $i<=$pagination_buttons; $i++){
                 if($i == $page){             
                   echo '<li class="active"><a href="domain.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                 }
                 else{
                  echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }
               }

               if($last_page > $pagination_buttons){
                 echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.($pagination_buttons+1).'">Next</a></li>';
               }          

             } 


            else if($page >= $pagination_buttons AND $last_page > $pagination_buttons){

              if(($page+$half) >= $last_page){
                echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.($last_page - $pagination_buttons).'">Previous</a></li>';

              for ($i=($last_page-$pagination_buttons)+1; $i<=$last_page; $i++) {

                 if($i == $page){             
                   echo '<li class="active"><a href="domain.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                  }
                 else{
                  echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                  }

               }
               }
               else if(($page+$half) < $last_page){
                  echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.(($page-$half)-1).'">Previous</a></li>';

                for ($i=($page-$half); $i<=($page+$half); $i++) {

                 if($i == $page){             
                   echo '<li class="active"><a href="domain.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                  }
                 else{
                  echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                  }

               }

               echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.(($page+$half)+1).'">Next</a></li>';
               }

            }  

            if($page != $total_pages && $total_pages >= 6){
              echo '<li><a href="domain.php?page='.$total_pages.'">Last</a></li>';
            } ?>
```

i solve it my code in pagination in php with mysql.. and hope may help this code your pagination project...
I coded pagination code for my site in php and mysql.. I wonder how to easily make pagination in PHP with MySQL.. May I ask you a favor of you? This my code have not error... take this code with your project implement..

Comment: What do you want to ask? It is unclear

Comment: i have solve it my coding so implement this code.. hope may help this code... thanks :)

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking.